# Focusing inputs in React infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am creating a simple quiz, which is just a bunch of inputs in a row, in which you type the answer. I am trying to add automatic focus to those input elements, with looping back to first input if the last one is submitted, and jumping over already answered question. I've managed to get the functionality I wanted, but when the user give too many incorrect asnwers, all of the inputs are set to disabled, and I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded", and I have no idea why. Here are my functions:

```
const getNextElement = (idx: number): HTMLInputElement | null => {
    //if all questions are done and disabled, return null
    if (totalFinished > focusRefs.current.length - 2) {
      return null;
    }

    const nextItem = focusRefs.current[idx];

    //if we are at the last element in focus refs, go back to start
    if (nextItem === undefined) {
      return getNextElement(0);
    }

    //if the input is disabled, try focusing on the next one
    //this one seems to be the source of the infinite loop
    if (isOn && nextItem.disabled) {
      return getNextElement(idx + 1);
    }

    return nextItem;
  };

  const focusInput = (name: string) => {
    //find current element index
    const foundElIdx = focusRefs.current.findIndex((el: HTMLInputElement) => {
      return el.name === name;
    });

    //get next element
    const nextElement = getNextElement(foundElIdx + 1);

    //TS check
    if (nextElement === null) {
      return;
    }

    nextElement.focus();
  };
```

I marked the problematic block with a comment. It somehow gets triggered even when isOn gets set to false in redux

Comment: Your component is rendering too many times. Therefore the max callstack is reached. You will have to provide the code for the entire component to figure out what's the problem. It can be in the useEffect, if you are using useEffect. It can be because you are setting state directly in the main Functional component and not in a wrapper function. There are several other reasons for an infinite loop.

Comment: When and how is disabled state or isOn state marked

Comment: Turns other component, to which I pass the focus funtion to as a prop, was the source of the error. I set a timer for answering a question in it, and when it expires, the answer is validated, and the next element is focused, and so on. I forgot to clear the timer when isOn gets changed to false, so the function for getting next element for focus was fired after some time, with no valid elements and hence the infinite loop.